# Can I use a generic type as object index type in TypesScript?

Tags: typescript, generics

I have a use case similar to the following:

```js
type StringKeysOf<T> = [{
  [K in keyof T]-?: T[K] extends string ? K : never
}[keyof T]];

const createDictionary = <T>(key: StringKeysOf<T>) => {

  let dictionary: { [key: string]: T } = {};

  const addToDictionary = (value: T) => {
    dictionary = { ...dictionary, [value[key]]: value }
  }

  return { dictionary, addToDictionary }
}
```

When trying to use the key attribute as an index type, TypeScript complains with the following message: `Type 'StringKeysOf<T>' cannot be used as an index type.`

I assume this is not possible because `T` could eventually hold a type which does not have any properties of type `string` (which I am filtering on `StringKeysOf` conditional type).

Does anyone knows if there is a way to make this implementation possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of things you can do to fix this. First, note that `StringKeysOf<T>` is an `Array` type. Given the name `key` and not `keys`, I assume you mean for the argument to be a single value. You need to remove the `[]`:

```
type StringKeysOf<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]-?: T[K] extends string ? K : never
}[keyof T];
```

Then, you need to make sure that your `T` has the shape that you expect:

```
T extends { [K in keyof T]: any }
```

Putting it all together: [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=14&pc=2#code/C4TwDgpgBAysBOBLAdgcwNIRAZwPIDMAeAFQD4oBeKAbwCgooBtdKFKAaywHt8piBdALQB+AFx9m-KBAAewCMgAm2KNgQpUUYVBbjkEAG4R4tAL6NOIHn34BuWrQDGXZGqiP4EAIbyAIokdgRBcveBBKKBJpOQVlGiYWNktrAXEvZHDTUgAKS3E4JDRMHAISUgBKSnI6eigAGwhgKEUAoJCw8WomPNV1NH5xYihTCOpTe1rnVyavRUViLn9A4ORQ8Kpsgy86gFcIQcqKatqGFuX29fiAOhuzttWwgBomLd2ICyx+AahXveHa0wOBieYA7eDIeJ3FZrZ6zeaLVrQsL-UxAA)

```
type StringKeysOf<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]-?: T[K] extends string ? K : never
}[keyof T];

const createDictionary = <T extends { [K in keyof T]: any }>(key: StringKeysOf<T>) => {

  let dictionary: { [key: string]: T } = {};

  const addToDictionary = (value: T) => {
    dictionary = { ...dictionary, [value[key]]: value }
  }

  return { dictionary, addToDictionary }
}
```